# An error occurs when sending multipart files using formData

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, multipart

I'd like to send a file using "formData". 
I'm using Spring boot for backend, and React.js for frontend. 
With PostMan, I checked the Spring boot to ensure that the files are stored properly. 
But when I attach a file to formData and send it, an error occurs.

Below is the error.

```
.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'file' is not present]
```

Below is a part of React.js

```
class Test extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
    this.state = {
        fileList:[]
    };
    this.uploadNewWebtoon = this.uploadNewWebtoon.bind(this);
            this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
}

onChange=({ fileList })=> {
    this.setState({ fileList }, function(){
        console.log(this.state.fileList[0].originFileObj)
     })
 }

 uploadNewWebtoon() {
    try {
        uploadFile(this.state.fileList[0].originFileObj)


    } catch(error) {
            notification.error({
                message: 'Cheeze Toon',
                description: error.message || 'Try again.'
            });
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="newAdd-container">
                <Form onSubmit={this.uploadNewWebtoon}>
                <Form.Item label="Thumbnail">
                        <Dragger onChange={this.onChange} beforeUpload={() => false} >
                            <p className="ant-upload-drag-icon">
                            <Icon type="inbox" />
                            </p>
                            <p className="ant-upload-text">Click or drag file to this area to upload</p>
                            <p className="ant-upload-hint">
                            Support for a single or bulk upload. Strictly prohibit from uploading company data or other
                            band files
                            </p>
                        </Dragger>
                    </Form.Item>
                    <Form.Item>
                        <Button type="primary" className="newAddButton" size="large" htmlType="submit">Save</Button>
                    </Form.Item>
                </Form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I'm using the React UI Library called Ant Design. So I followed the official document and used `this.state.fileList[0].originFileObj` in the same sense as `event.target.files[0]`.

orginFileObj of filesList[0] consists of the following

[image]

Below is the part that I create the formData, attach the file to append(), and transfer it to fetch.

```
import { API_BASE_URL, ACCESS_TOKEN} from '../constants';



const request = (options) => {
    const headers = new Headers()

    if(localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN)) {
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem(ACCESS_TOKEN))
    }

    const defaults = {headers: headers};
    options = Object.assign({}, defaults, options);

    return fetch(options.url, options)
    .then(response => 
        response.json().then(json => {
            if(!response.ok) {
                return Promise.reject(json);
            }
            return json;
        })
    );
};


export function uploadFile(fileList) {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('fileList', fileList);
        return request({
            url:API_BASE_URL + "/newToonSave",
            method: 'POST',
            body : formData
        })
}
```

JWT TOKEN is included in the header due to login function.

I tried to attach option after append value, (like fileName = fileList.name...)

 but the result was the same.

This is the spring boot controller part.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ToonController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ToonController.class);

    @Autowired
    private ToonStorageService toonStorageService;

    @PostMapping(value = "/newToonSave", consumes = {MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    public ToonStorage uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {

        ToonStorage toonStorage = toonStorageService.storeFile(file);

        return toonStorage;

    }

}
```

I don't know why it doesn't work...

I thought Spring boot needed a library related to file upload.

So I added Dependency to pom.xml and added @Bean to Application.java.

However, the same error occurs.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
//auto convert
@EntityScan(basePackageClasses = {DemoApplication.class, Jsr310JpaConverters.class})
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
    FileStorageProperties.class
})
public class DemoApplication {

    @PostConstruct
    void init(){
        TimeZone.setDefault(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement() {
    MultipartConfigFactory factory = new MultipartConfigFactory();
    return factory.createMultipartConfig();
    }

    @Bean
    public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(512000000);
    return multipartResolver;
    }

}
```

I've been struggling for four days. I would really appreciate your help.

Comment: If it works with postman but breaks with react, it’s a frontend problem. Inspect in chrome devtool network panel to see the shape of your request. You can see if “file” is missing or not, also check the headers for content-type to see if it is a multipart type

Comment: I suspect it should be `formData.append('file', fileList)`

Comment: I've made a foolish mistake.. Now, it works! Thanks so much